# How can non-Cocoa applications know when to rebuild menu bar?

Tags: macos, keyboard-maestro

My application (Keyboard Maestro) reads other applications menus via the accessibility API (eg AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue for kAXMenuBarAttribute et al).

This works fine for normal Mac Cocoa application, their menus are automatically kept up to date.

But for some cross platform applications (eg Finale 14, and lots of Adobe apps), their menus are not updated when accessibility requests are made.  So the user is left to perform some fake UI action (click in the menu bar, switch applications, or some other trick) to force the menus to be updated.

Is there any way to programatically encourage such applications to update their menubars, or alternatively is there some programatic way for such applications to be notified that they need to rebuild their menu bars (and then at least I could pass the information on to them).

Thanks.

Comment: It's going to depend on how they built their apps. In general one of the worst things of all about cross platform GUI libraries is that they don't support accessibility well because they would need to repeat the effort across all platforms or leverage more platform native frameworks.